# Why does Phillips Perron test say my data is stationary?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

**The problem**

I have quarterly data from 2009 Q1 to 2019 Q2, and I would like to run an ARIMA forecast model on this data. In order to do that, it is my understanding that I need to first make my data stationary. In order to check for stationarity I am using the Phillips-Perron test (also the ADF and KPSS). However, no matter what I do, this test (PP) always says my data is stationary, even if it is clearly not.

**The code**

```
myTs <- 
  ts(
    c(
      11.610964, 11.271903, 11.881645, 11.156598,
      10.929974, 11.239756, 10.991811, 10.225923,
      10.418824, 10.287102, 10.779385, 10.249459,
       9.910870, 10.520374, 10.096030,  9.401996,
       9.698216,  9.684524,  9.421818,  8.946004,
       8.683088,  9.579321,  8.925590,  7.951550,
       8.538138,  8.550782,  8.762871,  7.920771,
       8.060027,  7.551839,  8.914238,  7.914314,
       7.418662,  7.440925,  7.554222,  6.822691,
       7.028216,  6.720993,  6.711624,  6.478084,
       6.380212,  6.420553
    ), 
   start = c(2009, 1),
   frequency = 4
  )

forecast::autoplot(myTs)

stats::PP.test(myTs) # p-value = 0.01 --> no unit root
```

**The plot**

[image: autoplot]

**My questions**

It is my understanding that a small p-value rejects the null hypothesis of a unit root.

- Am I correct in thinking this test says that my data is stationary?
- Am doing something wrong when applying this function?
- How should I interpret this result? The data has a clear trend, and so should not be stationary.

Comment: The documentation for this test (at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tseries/tseries.pdf) says "The general regression equation which incorporates a constant and **a linear trend** is used". It's a test of stationarity after the non-stationarity due to a linear trend has been adjusted for.

Comment: @CloseToC That's not the function used here but the documentation for `stats::PP.test` says the same thing. You appear to have a "trend-stationary" series (i.e. a series which, once you remove a deterministic time trend, is stationary). This is a "milder" form of non-stationarity which is different from a unit root and can easily be handled by including the time trend in a regression-with-ARMA-errors model.

Comment: Is there any way to just test for a stationary time series, without linear trend? (Using the PP test I mean, I'm aware there are other tests.)